# DNF and CNF and Complexity Theory

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete

$F(z_1,...,z_n)$ is a Boolean expression. The assignment of variable ($x_1,...,x_n \in {0, 1}$) is the answer of $F$, if $F$ for that assignment equals to $1$.

If that case is true and the conditions are met, then both of them are considered to be *NP-Hard*.

---

A) The *number* of *answers* of $F$ in $DNF$ format.

B) The *number* of *answers* of $F$ in $CNF$ format.

> DNF and CNF are [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)

---

Can anyone describe to me in clear, simple, and concise words why both of them are true?

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of satisfying assignments to $F$ is at least as hard as determining whether there is a satisfying assignment.  (If the count is 0, there are no satisfying assignments; if the count is $\ge 1$, there is a satisfying assignment.)

For CNF formulas, testing whether there is a satisfying assignment is the SAT problem, which is a classic example of a NP-hard problem.

Counting the number of satisfying assignments of $F$ is at least as hard as determining whether all assignments satisfy $F$.  For DNF formulas, this is NP-hard, too.

Comment: am I true? we search for number of answer that assignment is 1 in a formula, equal to we search for all satisfiable case for that formula?

Comment: would you please answer my comments?

Comment: @LisaBerry, I don't understand your question, so I don't know how to answer it.  Sorry.

Comment: what is the meaning of "number of answers"? means all cases of assignment of variable that formula being satisfy?

Comment: @LisaBerry, You used that phrase, not me.  I assume it means "number of satisfying assignments".  Only you can know whether that's what you meant or not.